# Python Beginners - Searching a text file for an array of text

Tags: python, arrays

I'm brand new to python. I have a text file full of strings. I want to see which of these multiple strings contain a set of keywords. I've managed to write this:

```
f = open('C:\\blah\\list.txt')
for line in f:
    if 'keyword' in line:
        print line
```

Which works great! Its just, I have a lot of keywords to search, so I imagine I want to get an array in there somehow but I've looked, and can't find out how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry. What I'm try to do is search the text file for more than one keyword at a time. So like, if any of the strings in the file contain keyword1, or keyword2, or keyword3, print them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you searching for lines with **all** keywords included?

```
keywords = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

for line in f:
    if all(keyword in line for keyword in keywords):
        print line
```

or with **any** of them? In the latter case replace the `all` with `any`.